# Why is Hitman: Absolution causing a BSOD?

Tags: technical-issues, hitman-absolution

I have been playing *Hitman: Absolution* for quite some time now, and have begun coming across a problem. After playing for at least half an hour, I get the blue screen of death with the error `IRQL_NOT_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL`. It does not mention any specific files.

I use a *Vision Computer* with *Windows 8.1*, on an *Intel i7* with a *Geforce GTX 660M GPU* and 2GB graphics memory.
Nothing is overclocked. 
My mouse is a Razer naga 2014 (Model no.: `RZ01-0104`). I also have a Logitech MX518 mouse and a Logitech G600 mouse I can use if that might help.

All my drivers are updated.
No messages in windows log.

Any ideas for a fix would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to update all you drivers, blue screens of death are 99% of the time a driver issue or a hardware issue. Because you said it happens when you play hitman for a while my bet is on a faulty driver. Update your graphics card driver first. Also, do you have any external devices connected? If yes, which devices (brands, model)?

Comment: If the blue screen mentions any filenames, that can point you in the direction of the specific driver (or device) that is causing the issue.

Comment: @Kevin tried it, doesn't help

Comment: Any message in the [Windows Event Log](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-event-viewer.htm) ?

Comment: Are any of your parts overclocked?

Comment: `IRQL_NOT_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL` is almost certainly a driver problem or possibly a fault on your hardware. Your question *might* be better on [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com). I'd probably go with your nVidia drivers, are you using vendor supplier drivers or the nVidia drivers? I'd suggest using the nVidia ones if you aren't already. If you have the knowledge and equipment, it might be worth checking the voltages from your PSU also, as a undervolt PSU can cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: check this link -> http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1653275/fix-irql-equal-error-windows.html